# Cocos2d : tile maps VS 1 giant image

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have been doing some reading and tutorials on tile maps in cocos2d, but what i want is to have a large graphic map, not made up of tiles that the user can drag around. so my question is this.

Is it going to cause performance issues to have a large map, (this will be on the ipad so maybe x4 the screen size)?

Comment: Users can only drag the tiles around if you implement code to let them do so! Tiles aren't even visible as individual tiles - it all looks like one large background texture.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum texture size you can have is 2048x2048 for any device above the iPhone 3G (This includes all iPads, although it may be larger on the iPhone 4S, but I doubt it). You can find tons of links on google by a simple search of ***iphone max texture size***. That means that the largest image you can have is between 4-6 iPad screens. If this is enough for you, great! If not, you'll have to tile the screen anyways, regardless of the size of your tiles. Hope that Helps!